# Как скомпилировать программу под Windows

Tags: c, windows, кроссплатформенность, кросс-компиляция

Программа на Си, использует стандартную библиотеку + ncurses. Мультифайловая программа, для сборки используется утилита make. Подскажите наиболее простой способ скомпилировать ее на Windows на виртуалке (что установить/использовать).

PS Если кто знает как сделать подобное через wine - тоже пишите, такой вариант тоже меня устраивает, главное чтобы скомпилированный файл работал на Windows.

Исходный код:
https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/sudoku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что есть простой способ, ncurses очень UNIX ориентированна (для Windows используется PDCurses). Однако вы можете:

1. Установить [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) и [MSYS](http://mingw.org/wiki/msys).
2. Скачать [ncurses](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/).
3. Внимательно изучив **README.MinGW** в корневой папке ncurses'а, скомпилировать библиотеку.
4. Скомпилировать вашу программу (возможно нужно будет внести некоторые изменения в Makefile, указать путь к библиотеке и заголовочным файлам, но уверен вы разберётесь).

Некоторые нюансы:

- Eсли в вашем коде вы обращаетесь к ncurses через `#include <ncurses.h>` могут возникнуть проблемы (скомпилированный вами ncurses может иметь другой заголовочный файл, например `ncurses_mingw.h`), но даже если никаких проблем нет, я настоятельно рекомендую изменить `#include <ncurses.h>` на `#include <curses.h>` это не только решит потенциальные проблемы (которые я уверен все же возникнут), но так же это просто "правильней" если хотите (недаром в man page указанно именно `curses.h`).
- Будьте осторожны с переменной **TERM**, скорей всего она должна быть "пустой" (`export TERM=`), а может и нет (короче будьте осторожны).

Comment: От себя добавлю: скомпилировать библиотеку ncurses под виндой не получилось... Поэтому я использовал pdcurses - аналог ncurses на виндоус. Но ответ был мне полезен